# Event reminder not working for calendar events in android

Tags: android, calendar, reminders

My calendar application (version 2.3) adds the calendar event for user, but the reminder is not working. I have set `event.put("hasAlarm", 1);` like this.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following
`event.put(Events.HAS_ALARM,1);`

where import is 
`import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;`

use this import `import android.provider.Calendar.Events;` for 2.3

Comment: thanks  for ur suggestion. but i think it will be applicable in higher versions only... mine is 2.3

Comment: import android.provider.Calendar.Events no such imports in 2.3